# Что было проделано в своде каменного мешка?

Tags: литература, смысл

Из "Собора Парижской Богоматери" (про Эсмеральду в тюрьме):

> *Она подняла голову и увидела красноватый свет проникавший сквозь щели дверцы или крышки люка, который **был проделан** в своде каменного мешка.*

Люк был проделан? Разве так говорят? Не свет же был проделан! Неудачный перевод?

Comment: Артём, скажите, а вы всю книгу читаете или только одно предложение вам попалось? Вы приняли ответ про «световой люк», однако в книге говорится, что она находится в темнице в подземелье, где нет света. О каком «световом люке» может идти речь? Я под тем ответом привёл цитаты из книги. Свет, о котором говорится в вашей цитате, идёт от фонаря, который принесли, те кто к ней пришли. А через этот люк до этого ей давали еду. Таким образом, это просто отверстие с крышкой в потолке темницы, которая по содержанию книги является ямой, одним «из каменных мешков, вырытых по приказанию Людовика Святого...».

Comment: @Eagle Встречный вопрос. А вы по моей ссылке хоть что-то прочитали? Прежде чем делать столь безапелляционные заявления?

Comment: @behemothus Ваша ссылка это не настоящая Википедия, а машинный перевод статьи из англоязычной википедии [Skylight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylight). То, что переведено как «световой люк», в оригинале «skylight», и никаким люком не является.

Comment: @Eagle если вам не нравится источник, то это ваши проблемы. Я полагаю английскую википедию уж никак не менее авторитетной, чем русская. Про машинный перевод - это вы загнули. Машинный перевод без единой грамматической ошибки просто невозможен. Если же есть сомнения в переводе термина, то не сочтите за труд посмотреть хотя бы сюда:  https://translate.google.ru/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA&op=translate

Comment: И вообще, давайте сосредоточимся не на критике источников, а на вашем комментарии. Вы утверждаете (более того: требуете? чтобы автор вопроса принял вашу точку зрения!), что понятие "световой люк" не может распространяться на описанную у Гюго ситуацию? Ну так докажите это логически. Ваши ссылки на цитаты некорректны, пример не одного использования не может опровергнуть другого.

Comment: @Eagle: ну к ней пришёл один только архиепископ вообще-то. Хорошо, от фонаря, тогда уже неправильно называть его световым люком?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  тут дело даже не в том, кто к кому пришел, а в самой постановке вопроса вашим собеседником. Я не пойму чего он добивается своими опровержениями непонятно чего. skylight вообще наряду со световым люком имеет перевод "верхний свет".

Comment: Я почти не знаю французского и не имею текста, но скорее всего там использовано слово "lucarne" одним из переводов которого как раз и является "световой люк".

Comment: @Артём Луговой Конечно неправильно. В приведенной в качестве доказательства статье (а на самом деле машинном переводе статьи): _А световой люк (иногда называемый кровельным светом) представляет собой светопропускающую конструкцию, которая формирует все или часть кровля пространство здания **для дневного освещения**_. Во-первых, «для дневного освещения», т. е. пропускает дневной свет. А во-вторых, то, что это корявый машинный перевод видно невооружённым глазом.

Comment: @Артём Луговой _«ну к ней пришёл один только архиепископ вообще-то»_. «В ту же минуту тяжелый засов загремел, крышка люка, заскрипев на ржавых петлях, откинулась, и она увидела фонарь, руку и **ноги двух человек**».

Comment: Ага, но второй ушёл и не говорится, кто это был.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой тут, как говорят юристы, "вновь открывшиеся обстоятельства"  возникли, что еще раз перевернуло мои представления о смысле самой фразы. Добавил в текст ответа.

Comment: @Артём Луговой _«Ага, но второй ушёл и не говорится, кто это был»._ Ну пришли то двое, а вы сделали замечание, что пришёл один на мой комментарий. Хотя я вообще не понимаю, какой это имеет отношение к сути вопроса.

Comment: @behemothus: отлично, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ. Прочтите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой У меня не все получилось, мой информатор не выказал интереса к теме. Но вот здесь, надеюсь, мне (и вам) дадут содержательный ответ. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=7048#p549155 посматривайте периодически, пока это для вас актуально, я пока возьму тайм-аут.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду посматривать!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Люк был проделан?

Люк, конечно. Именно он.
Мне стилистически ближе тут "был сделан" или, скажем, "был пробит" (в зависимости от контекста, я его, конечно, не помню, а искать сил нет). Но не вижу причин сомневаться в корректности "люк проделан".

> Разве так говорят?

А почему нет? Примеров полно в других ответах, не буду повторяться.
Хотелось бы более подробно ваши сомнения.

Возможно я ничего не добавил к другим ответам, но для меня всегда важно ответить именно на тот вопрос, который явно задан. И именно в том виде, как он задан.
Поэтому я и добавил свои пять копеек в уже решенный (вроде бы) по сути вопрос.

(+) в отношении люк=отверстие. Вот тут не совсем согласен.
Люк вроде бы предполагает возможность пролезть в него или просунуть какую-то часть тела. А, например, смотровое отверстие даже с крышкой - это глазок, но не люк.
Если в тексте имелся в виду именно такое отверстие, "непролазное", то это действительно некая ошибка, не знаю уж, переводчика или автора...
Но это ошибка именно в использовании слова "люк", не слова "проделан" и не их сочетания.

(++) Я частично снимаю сказанное ранее, но не настолько, чтобы давать другой ответ.
Я всё понял. Имеется в виду **"световой люк"** - это узаконенное архитектурное название специального отверстия в своде зданий определенного типа (к примеру-собора).
А раз так, и это именно такое отверстие, то такой "люк" вполне себе "проделан". В этом случае не имеется в виду, что "проделывание" осуществлялось в готовой конструкции, что возможно при использовании "пробит". Немного сомневаюсь, что такие люки оборудовались дверцами или крышками (как в тексте), но раз сам Гюго такое пишет (это-то явно не переводческая блажь), то придется принять на веру.

(+++)
Вот о чем речь идет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://tftwiki.ru/wiki/Skylight

Тут можно даже понять, что крышки у них были едва ли не обязательным элементом. Всё сходится.

(++++)=====
@Eagle , как я понимаю, ошибочно принял мой пример светового люка за единственно возможный. Я же полагаю, что нет ничего некорректного в том, что люком названа конструкция в своде помещения, а не здания.

(+++++) ======= 07.08.21
Я нашел французский текст.

Un jour enfin ou une nuit (car minuit et midi avaient même couleur dans ce sépulcre), elle entendit au-dessus d'elle un bruit plus fort que celui que faisait d'ordinaire le guichetier quand il lui apportait son pain et sa cruche. Elle leva la tête, et vit un rayon rougeâtre passer à travers les fentes de l'espèce de porte ou de trappe pratiquée dans la voûte de l'in-pace. En même temps la lourde ferrure cria, la trappe grinça sur ses gonds rouillés, tourna, et elle vit une lanterne, une main et la partie inférieure du corps de deux hommes, la porte étant trop basse pour qu'elle pût apercevoir leurs têtes. La lumière la bénédiction si vivement qu'elle ferme les yeux.

К сожалению, он мне не по силам, а результаты от гугл-переводчика вызывают большие сомнения. По первому впечатлению люк (или что оно там) было совсем не в своде помещения. В таком случае это, конечно, не световой люк, а самый обычный (слово "люк" - la trappe - там есть, "свода" - l'arcade - я там не увидел). Но тогда мы возвращаемся к вопросу об адекватности перевода.
Завтра спрошу у человека, в чьем французском не сомневаюсь.
Вопрос будет стоять так. ***Где был проделан "люк", если судить по тексту оригинала, и при чем тут "свод каменного мешка"?*** Не возражаете против такой постановки вопроса?

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус! Жалко, что не могу принять оба ответа (ответ Александра собираюсь принять за мысль, что это не крышка).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Так принимайте)))). Я в общем-то давно стал равнодушен в целом к этим поцелуям в репутацию, а в данном случае я и не претендовал на большее, чем простое дополнение к уже сказанному.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Тьфу, Артем! Я вдруг всё понял. См. текст ответа.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!)) А можно перед "едва" запятую убрать или фраза читается иначе как-то (например, в смысле "и едва" или "причём едва")?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да всё можно, но я уже это сделал. ))) Извините, совсем не в форме чтобы свой текст вычитывать, мне это всегда трудно давалось, сейчас - особенно. Так что такие вещи правьте смело, я всегда смогу откатить.

Comment: У вас интересная мысль насчёт светового люка, однако речь идёт про темницу. До этого в книге написано: _«Если какое-либо несчастное существо попадало туда, **то должно было сказать прости свету**, воздуху, жизни, ogni speranza»_. Там не было света.

Comment: Дальше по тексту: _«**И вот она здесь, затерянная в кромешной тьме**, погребенная, зарытая, замурованная»_. Света нет.

Comment: Далее: _«Так, оцепенев, заледенев, окаменев, она почти не слышала, как раза два-три где-то над головой **с шумом открывался люк, не пропуская при этом ни малейшего света; через этот люк чья-то рука бросала ей корку черного хлеба**»_. Люк не пропускал никакого света, потому что это подземелье. Через люк бросали еду. Таким образом, это именно отверстие с крышкой.

Comment: А теперь более полная цитата, по которой был вопрос: _«Она подняла голову и увидела красноватый свет, проникавший сквозь щели дверцы или крышки люка, который был проделан в своде каменного мешка.
   **В ту же минуту тяжелый засов загремел, крышка люка, заскрипев на ржавых петлях, откинулась, и она увидела фонарь**, руку и ноги двух человек»_. Свет был от фонаря (искусственного источника света), который принесли.

Comment: То, что у вас на изображении называется «О́кулюс, о́кулус (лат. oculus — глаз), или опейон (греч. ὀπαῖον — дымовое отверстие; также опайон, опеон) — круглое отверстие в центре крыши или купола» [Википедия]. На вашей картинке изображён окулюс в куполе римского Пантеона. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку, где окюлюс называется «световым люком». И где можно увидеть архитектурное «узаконенное» определение светового люка?

Comment: @Eagle можно поконкретнее? Понятие "Световой люк" не ограничивается собором и естестваенным светом. Главное, что он проделан в своде здания. *То, что у вас на изображении называется «О́кулюс, о́кулус (лат. oculus — глаз),* - и что? Вы по моей по ссылке-то ходили?  Там это названо именно "световым люком". Короче, формулируйте замннчания к ответу - я их с радостью выслушаю, а все остальное - разговоры ни о чем.

Comment: Я не знаю, что за левая Википедия у вас по ссылке. В настоящей Википедии в статье про мансардное окно нет никаких люков: [Мансардное окно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE). Вы привели фото окулюса. А окулюс изначально вообще делался для выхода дыма, а не поступления света.

Comment: @eagle а я не знаю, чего вы добиваетесь. Один источник так называет - другой этак... При том что примеров использования термина "световой люк" именно в таком значении - тьма. А ваши окулюсы мало кому известны. И вообще - это не предмет для обсуждения в комментариях.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128322/discussion-between-behemothus-and-eagle).

Answer (score 3):

Первая реакция на это выражение может быть связана с тем, что в быту "люк" ассоциируется с *крышкой* канализационного люка. Она на виду и люди обычно не задумываются о том, что под ней. Но "люк" - это закрывающееся **отверстие** (зачастую в объёмном массиве) или **ход** для доступа к чему-то, а отверстие (дыру) именно "проделывают". В литературе достаточно примеров "проделывания люка" (реже его "делают" или "устраивают").

(Дюма, Виконт де Бражелон, изд. 2021)

> ...по собственной воле, в таком месте *проделал люк*, предназначенный...

(Амеде Ашар, В огонь и воду, 2017)

> ...а в своде *проделал люк*, да так искусно, что его нельзя было и
> заметить.

(А. Орлов, Точка орбитального удара, 2018)

> Самым простым было *проделать люк*, усилить крышу дополнительным листом
> железа и на него установить пулемет...

(Г. Романов, Спасти Колчака! 2020)

> И *люк* в полу вагонов *проделать*, для экстренного выход...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, мысли о крышке были, поэтому глагол и казался странным.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарю Ожегова:

> **Люк**, лю́ка, м. Закрывающееся отверстие, напр. на палубе корабля, в
> полу сцены, в борту судна, самолёта, в танке.

Таким образом, люк — это разновидность отверстия, отверстие с крышкой.

В том же словаре:

> **Проде́лать**, -аю, -аешь; -анный; сов., что. 1. Сделать отверстие в
> чём-н. П. ход в заборе.

«Проделать люк» — значит проделать отверстие, которое будет закрываться крышкой.

В толковом словаре Даля:

> **Люк** м. морск. прорубь в настилке, в палубе, с крышкою к нему, для
> входа и выхода, нагрузки; вообще, вход в подполье, в погреб, лаз,
> лежачая дверь, западня, ляда. Лючный, к люку относящ.

Даль люком называет прорубь — то, что прорубили.

Поэтому, на мой взгляд, допустимо сказать: «проделать люк», «прорубить люк» и т. п.

Такое словосочинение есть в книге Алекса Орлова [Точка орбитального удара](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dec_DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Самым простым было **проделать люк**, усилить крышу дополнительным листом
> железа и на него установить пулемет, а то и пушечную турель.

В Интернете также встречается такое словосочинение:

> *Как **проделать люк** в подвал?* [[mastergrad.com](https://mastergrad.com/forums/t28463-kak-prodelat-lyuk-v-podval/)]
>
> ***Проделать люк** в гипсокартонном коробе.* [[kakpostroit.su](https://kakpostroit.su/potolok-zvezdnoe-nebo-svoimi-rukami/)]
>
> *А когда не обнаружили ни бетона ни грунта, добились разрешения **проделать люк**.* [[1tv.ru](https://www.1tv.ru/news/2016-10-14/311959-istoriki_i_poiskoviki_pytayutsya_razgadat_gde_spryatana_vyvezennaya_gitlerovtsami_yantarnaya_komnata)]

---

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Насчёт правильности перевод — перевод является точным.

В оригинале:

> Elle leva la tête, et vit un rayon rougeâtre passer à travers les
> fentes de l’espèce de porte ou de trappe pratiquée dans la voûte de
> l’in-pace.

В толковом словаре французского языка предоставляемом переводчиком Google:

> **Trappe**
> Ouverture pratiquée dans un plancher ou un plafond et munie d'une fermeture qui se rabat.
> [[translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=ru&text=trappe&op=translate)]
>
> Если перевести:
> *Отверстие проделанное в полу или потолке и оснащённое закрывающейся крышкой.*

Таким образом, перевод французского слова «trappe» русским словом «люк» точный.

Слово «voûte» означает «свод»: если сравнить значения слов, по толковым словарям французского и русского языка, перевод верный.

*«…trappe pratiquée dans la voûte…»* — *«…люк проложен в своде…»*.

---

Тут идёт речь об ублиете:

> **Ублие́т, ублие́тка (фр. oubliette, от фр. oublier — забывать) —
> подземная тюрьма в средневековых замках, в виде колодца с дверью
> наверху; «каменный мешок»**. В неё сбрасывали осуждённых на голодную
> смерть или пожизненное заключение (отсюда название). На Руси аналогом
> ублиета служил по́руб — яма с бревенчатым срубом, куда опускали
> заключённого, а в странах Востока — зиндан.

Например, ублиет Уорикского замка, Великобртания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ir0nee/8011602936), автор [ir0nee](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ir0nee/).

Аналогичная конструкция в Каменец-Подольской крепости, Украина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения [meganews.kiev.ua](http://forum.meganews.kiev.ua/viewtopic.php?t=20912&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15), пользователь Soldat.

Зиндан (восточный аналог ублиета) крепость Нарын-кала, Дагестан:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения [aquamarine-moscow.ru](https://aquamarine-moscow.ru/finland/kto-postroil-naryn-kala-derbentskaya-krepost-naryn-kala-dagestan-gde.html).

Камера Эсмеральды представляет собой яму, в потолке которой есть люк. Через этот люк осуществляется доступ в камеру.

Comment: Спасибо! Немного знаю французский, но сейчас нету времени и голова не хочет соображать на эту тему, поэтому просто поверю. И спасибо за примеры с картинками! Проголосовал за ответ.

Comment: Даже не знал, кстати, что там есть и толковый словарь. Спасибо, что обратили моё внимание на это!